# How can I connect a Howler.JS instance to a single start/stop button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, howler.js

I've managed to connect a few buttons to audio sources using Howler.js. However, I can't get the stop functionality to work because Howl creates a new Howl instance every time. Does anyone have any hints to directly connect sound.stop() to the same instance created on sound.start()? I'd like to be able to make multiple buttons this way without copying all the code for each sound! Here's my code:

```
var arrayVariable = ["Kick","Snare","HiHats"];
var newArr = [];
var arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
var temp;

$(document).ready(function(){

// create buttons //
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      newArr[i] = './audio/checklist/' + arrayVariable[i] + '.ogg';
      temp = document.createElement('button');
      temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
      var assign = $('#buttonDiv')[0].appendChild(temp);
      }
$('button').on('click',function() {
      var index = $( "button" ).index( this );
      //$( "div" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
      var i = $('#buttonDiv').index(this);

// configure howler //
      var sound = new Howl({
      src: [newArr[index]],
      autoplay: false,
      loop: true,
      volume: 0.5
      });

// start stop buttons //
      if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      sound.stop();
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')

      } else {

      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      sound.play();
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
      }
      });
      });
```

Comment: Play will give you a soundId, that you can then pass into stop to stop that sound.

Comment: Thank you James! I was aware that this is how Howler is set up, but am a bit confused about how do that. Do you have an example of how to retrieve and pass that soundID?